# How to get the parent structure as Spy++ gives it?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

In our code, a C++ class that is derived from `CMDIChildWnd` is instantiated and its `Create()` function is called, which is actually `CMDIChildWnd::Create()`.  The 5th parameter `pParentWnd` is being set to a `CMDIFrameWnd` object.  This in turn (within the MFC code) sets up a `CREATESTRUCT` object, sets it's `hwndParent` to that parameter and then calls `PreCreateWindow()` with that object passed as one of the parameters.

However, when going up the parent window list using `CWnd::GetParent()` (original) `GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_PARENT)` (just a try, since the original didn't work and this code is 20+ years old) and even `GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)` just to see if it was setting the window's owner for some reason.  In each case, I do not see the handle which is associated with the `CMDIFrameWnd` object.  Instead, the parent shown is the desktop, and owner is NULL.

Using Spy++, it shows what I was expecting.  How would I get the layout given by Spy++ programmatically?

Comment: `AfxGetMainWnd()` should return the main frame window. `CMDIChildWnd` is usually passed to `CMultiDocTemplate`, I am not familiar with the usage you are describing.

Comment: Use Spy++ to see the true window hierarchy. That will reflect the relationship without any code in between, that may or may not do something to be helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable, I have used spy++, and it shows what I want to see, but how do I get that answer in code?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I'm not looking for the root `CMDIFrameWnd`.  I'm looking for the one that is the parent to a particular `CMDIChildWnd`.  We have some `CMDIFrameWnd` which are parented to other `CMDIFrameWnd` windows.

Comment: MDI is odd, it comes with its own API. See if [Multiple Document Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/multiple-document-interface) has the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable, great, thanks.  Our system is an MDI / multiple desktop window (where the frame is hidden, making it visually look like the windows are rooted to the desktop) hybrid.  I'll take a look at the documentation, but I was hoping for a lower level answer which would be more generally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In MDI interface `CMDIChildWnd` is usually passed to `CMultiDocTemplate`, then we create a new window through `CDocManager::OnFileNew`, that in turn calls `CFrameWnd::LoadFrame` which passes `NULL` for child window's parent (at least in VS 2017)

We usually don't call `mdi_child->Create` directly, unless we initialize everything else manually. Perhaps you mean the base class `CMDIChildWnd::Create` is called, or you are able to override it.

In child window,

`::GetAncestor(m_hWnd, GA_ROOT)` or `::GetAncestor(m_hWnd, GA_ROOTOWNER)`

Should return a reference to the main frame, otherwise use `AfxGetMainWnd()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't write this code. It is 5+ years old and I've been here only 3. `mdi_child->Create()` was called by our code. We are not loading a new file. We're generating a frame to be used by a Chromium CEF window.  What sort of things would be initialized manually?